# Re-perform a merge that was previously conducted with Git

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a repository which was branched for a change (myChange1). Since that branch a number of commits had happened against the development branch (develop), and the feature branch also underwent a series of changes.

Eventually the feature branch (myChanges1) was merged back in to 'develop', for the purpose of adding a single file. This resulted in 'develop' remaining unchanged, except for the addition of this single file, and was conducted by clicking merge; then resetting all the files that weren't needed in the uncommitted-merge-changes, before finally committing the merge.

I have since made a number of changes on 'develop', and would like to re-perform the previously conducted merge, to bring in all features on the feature branch (myChange1), however when I try to conduct the merge again on the head of 'develop', Git believes it has already been conducted (which it has) and the final result doesn't exhibit the changes of this feature branch (myChange1), it only contains the single file from the initial merge, and the newest state of 'develop'.

How do I resolve this problem, and end up with a working set that includes the head of 'develop', and the entire feature branch's changes?

Is there a better way to have done the initial merge at the time?

(Using Source Tree and Bitbucket, all functions where conducted via the UI).

Comment: I would have tried to add the one file without doing a merge (git can handle this in the later merge) but now that it's done and, I assume, published and copied elsewhere, I'd just re-do the merge as a "real merge" (making a new branch for it), trying a few different methods to see what turns out to be the simplest—but I only know how to do this with command line tools.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback torek. I tried heaps of different combinations of branching, touching files, and merging, but kept resulting in the same outcome via the UI. I didn't want to elaborate on them too much in my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I ended up just opening both version and updating the files manually, but the situation will inevitably resurface in the future. I guess the take-away is that I just need to learn Git (the command line tool) properly - I've been really put off by the inconsistency in the commands, flags, and syntax; like much of the unix world that I haven't authored myself.
Thanks again!